# Change the language of datepicker

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a function that changes the language of date picker

```
$(function(){
txtDate = $("#txtDate");
var minDate = new Date(2011, 1 - 1, 15);
var maxDate = new Date(2011, 6 - 1, 15);
txtDate.date
txtDate.dateEntry({
            defaultDate: maxDate,
            minDate: minDate,
            maxDate: maxDate,
            spinnerImage: ''
        });
txtDate.datepicker({
            minDate: minDate,
            maxDate: maxDate
        });

txtDate.datepicker("setDate", maxDate);
dateLanguageChange();
});


var dateLanguageChange = function () {
        $("#txtDate").datepicker("destroy").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
    };
```

html:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label>@Html.Resource("Date")</label>
    <input id="txtDate" type="text" class="date-box" />
</div>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI or some other plugin, please mention that and tag this question appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

have you tried using [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) It's a highly configurable plugin and provides support for localizing its content to cater for different languages and date formats.

```
$(function() {
$("#txtDate").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
minDate: '-10y',
maxDate: 'now',         
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
firstDay: 1
});
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
});
```

your html

```
<input id="txtDate" type="text" class="date-box" />
```

Note:configure datepicker options accordingly....make sure to include *jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js*  Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Isn't this code already using jQuery UI's datepicker? I think the `.datepicker("destroy")` function is unique to jQuery UI's datepicker

Comment: I using the datepicker. I have trouble changing the culture. I am sure its just a coding error.